# Bad result of the tensorflow sequence to sequence demo

Tags: python, tensorflow

I do what the official tutorial tells about the tensorflow sequence to sequence
model . This is my steps and results:
Training Commands:

```
python translate.py
```

--data_dir [your_data_directory] --train_dir [checkpoints_directory]
  --size=256 --num_layers=2 --steps_per_checkpoint=50

Then I have run it for one week.Now this is the log result:
[log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b06Q.png)

Since the training corpus contains ~22M sentences, one epoch (going through the training data once) takes about 340K steps with batch-size of 64. 
You can see it will run over.And the learing rate is very very small.
Now I decode ,this is my command:

`python translate.py --decode --data_dir ./corpus/ --train_dir      ./checkPointDir2 --size=256 --num_layers=2`

This is the decode result:
[decode result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F479L.png)

The first sentence is what the example of tutorial, you can see it is good.
But the rest sentences is bad ,so I am confused .it is really so bad or should I have to chang the model parameters ? I want to konw if anyone runs 
this demo and the result is just like me or not? Am I wrong with something?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Do other sentences work? Seems like short ones don't do so well. Also, is it really necessary to train that long?

Comment: I  am also confused .It is so long .I just do as the website and I do not change any code .But In the log file ,it doesn't have any erros. The other sentence doesn't work very well.

Comment: Thank you very much @chris_anderson ! I check the code and find that in the train steps there is a while(true){.....}. That means the training steps will run forever.